# Text garbled in fbterm

Tags: linux, command-line, fbterm

The text in fbterm is garbled, and I can't come up with any more ideas. $TERM is set to fbterm, no problem there. In addition, tput colors reports 256 colors. I've tried different fonts, makes no difference at all.

The machine is a Powerbook G3 "Pismo" with an ATI Rage 128 graphics card and 1024x768 native resolution.

Any suggestions?

[image: fbcat screenshot]

Comment: Maybe you have a very old version of tool, there was a bug "Bug 48304 - text in fbterm is garbled ": https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=48304

Comment: Could be, but I doubt it. First of all, that bug report seems to indicate that the cause was a specific patch (infinality), which I haven't installed. In addition, the screenshot shows a different kind of problem, i.e. no letters at all, whereas I get letters, but with strange colors/patterns that cannot be changed.

Comment: @Tonyl did you ever find a solution?  I am having the same problem myself

Answer (score 0):

I've ran fbterm on a couple of different distros in Virtualbox and the only fonts which render correctly are bitmap fonts.  This wasn't always the case but that's abandonware for you.

Good fonts to check out are Terminus, Spleen, & GohuFont.

You'll need to do this after installing your font:

```
fc-cache -r
fc-list | less # then look for your font in the output
```

fc-list gives the following format per line:

/path/to/font.xyz: **name**:style=Style

Get the **name** of your font and open `~/.fbtermrc`.  If that file doesn't exist, just run fbterm once and exit.  fbterm creates the file during the first execution.

Where it says `font-names:<font>` in the file, put your font name.